# How many times was a shared link clicked on?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, data-explorer

**Background**

The [Announcer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/74/announcer) is awarded to people who share a link that results in 25 distinct IPs clicking on it. To track that the URLs are constructed like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860971/569976.

The first number is the post ID and the second number is the user ID.

**The Question**

Is it possible to see how many times a link was shared using data.stackexchange.com?  I'd expect a table `Links` or something to be used to keep track of how many people clicked on a particular link, but unless I'm missing it I'm just not seeing such a table?

Comment: Related: [View progress towards Announcer badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to see how many people you've refered to a question or answer? (And if not, can it be made possible, please?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93839/is-it-possible-to-see-how-many-people-youve-refered-to-a-question-or-answer-a)

Comment: Related: [View analytics for referral links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108738/view-analytics-for-referral-links)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That information is not available in the Data Explorer data set, no.

The data is only available internally; and not visible even on the regular sites until the badge is awarded.

Comment: So is the Data Explorer data set just a bunch of (MySQL-like) views or something?

Comment: essentially, yes @neu - it's based on the same sanitized subset as the public data dump.

Comment: I didn't know stackoverflow did datadumps. I did Google searches to try to find them to no avail. I guess they're normally available as Torrents and are *.xml files? idk either way I can't find them!

Comment: @neubert http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @neubert The data dumps are currently being released as torrent of XML dumps, seeded by clearbits, [here's the latest](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump). The release method [may be changing in the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170405/options-for-community-data-dump).